# Getting "Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent."error in download file

Tags: model-view-controller

I am getting after download file in login page.

In JS,

```
$('#DownloadForm').on('click', function (event) {       
  window.location = '/Form/Form1'
});
```

In controller,

```
public void Form1()
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Form/Form.xls")
    FileStream objFileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path);
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Form.xls");
    Response.AppendHeader("content-length", objFileStream.Length.ToString());
    int nSize = 0;
    byte[] arrBuffer = new byte[1024 * 215];
    while ((nSize = objFileStream.Read(arrBuffer, 0, arrBuffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        Response.OutputStream.Write(arrBuffer, 0, nSize);
        Response.Flush();
    }
    Response.End();
}
```

I am getting error in Global.asax

protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
"Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent."

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start with Response.Clear();

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply.I test that, still getting error. If i call that function form other page I not getting error, if I call from login page I got error.